# When click a button in jsp it again call ready function in js. Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a button in jsp

```
<button id="btnViewAll">View All</button>
```

When I click it, I want to call viewAllInventory() function in js.

```
function viewAllInventory() {
$.ajax({
    url : "/GradleSpringMVC/inventory/viewAll",
    type : 'POST',
    dataType : 'json',
    data : JSON.stringify(populateViewAllParam()),
    contentType : 'application/json',
    mimeType : 'application/json'
}).done(
        function(response) {
            createInventoryTable(response);
        }).fail(function(error) {
    // parseToPageAlerts(error.responseText);
}).always(function() {
    // hideLoading()
});}
```

But when I debug js file. It calls again only ready function in js. Not call to viewAllInventory function.

My ready function in js is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("body").off("click", "#btnAdd").on("click", "#btnAdd", doAdd);
$("body").off("click", "#btnClear").on("click", "#btnClear", doClearAll);
$("body").off("click", "#btnSearch").on("click", "#btnSearch", doSearch);
$("body").off("click", "#btnDelete").on("click", "#btnDelete", deleteRow);
$("body").off("click", "#btnViewAll").on("click", "#btnViewAll", viewAllInventory);
 });
```

All the ajax call works well, I want to work this line correctly

```
$("body").off("click", "#btnViewAll").on("click", "#btnViewAll", viewAllInventory);
```

Can anybody give me an idea, Why this happen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and it works for me. I think the problem probably in your html.

If you have **btnViewAll** button within a **form** element, then each button click submits that form hence reloading the page so add

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

in your

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
......
......
}
```

function so that you can prevent the form submission. 
Or if you are not doing any form submission (only ajax type POSTing) then you can simply remove the form element.

Answer (score 0):

We can resolve this isue with changing `<button id="btnViewAll">View All</button>`  to `<button type="button" id="btnViewAll">View All</button>` . We need to add `type="button"` otherwise it is recognized as submit button.